# .SingleOrDefaultAsync Query result Select Top(2)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I started learning Web API and I am going through Microsoft "Using Web Api 2 with Entity FrameWork 6". as shown http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5

I am trying to understand how await and .SingleOrDefaultAsyn work.

In the BooksController, GetBook(int id), if I use

```
var book = await db.Books.Include(b => b.Author)
                 .Where(b => b.Id == id)
                 .Select(b => new BookDetailDTO()
                  {
                     Id = id,
                     Title = b.Title,
                     Price = b.Price,
                     AuthorName = b.Author.Name,
                     Genre = b.Genre,
                     Year = b.Year
                  }).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

from Output window, it shows

```
SELECT 
    [Limit1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Limit1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Limit1].[Title] AS [Title], 
    [Limit1].[Price] AS [Price], 
    [Limit1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Limit1].[Genre] AS [Genre], 
    [Limit1].[Year] AS [Year]
    FROM ( SELECT TOP (2) 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[Title] AS [Title], 
        [Extent1].[Year] AS [Year], 
        [Extent1].[Price] AS [Price], 
        [Extent1].[Genre] AS [Genre], 
        [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name], 
        @p__linq__1 AS [C1]
        FROM  [dbo].[Books] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Authors] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[AuthorId] = [Extent2].[Id]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[Id] = @p__linq__0) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NOT NULL)
    )  AS [Limit1]
```

But if I use the code as in the example on the above website, that is

```
 var book = await db.Books.Include(b => b.Author).Select(b => new BookDetailDTO()
                                {
                                    Id = b.Id,
                                    Title = b.Title,
                                    Price = b.Price,
                                    AuthorName = b.Author.Name,
                                    Genre = b.Genre,
                                    Year = b.Year
                                }).SingleOrDefaultAsync(b => b.Id == id);
```

I get the following:

```
SELECT TOP (2) 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Title] AS [Title], 
    [Extent1].[Price] AS [Price], 
    [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[Genre] AS [Genre], 
    [Extent1].[Year] AS [Year]
    FROM  [dbo].[Books] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Authors] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[AuthorId] = [Extent2].[Id]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[Id] = @p__linq__0) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NOT NULL)
```

My questions are:

1. why EF uses SELECT TOP (2)? I thought SingleOrDefaultAsync returns only one element or null?
2. which code is better in terms of efficiency and as a preferred method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. why EF uses SELECT TOP (2)? I thought SingleOrDefaultAsync returns only one element or null?

Because `Single` or `SingleOrDefault` will throw **an exception if more than one item** is found. That can be determined with `SELECT TOP (2)`, If two records are returned that means some thing is wrong and it will throw the exception.

> 1. which code is better in terms of efficiency and as a preferred method?

You have to measure their execution using [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx), I don't think there is going to be much of a difference.

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense to use top 2 as an indicator of exception. By looking at the SQL output, the first option is merely a wrapper around a sub-query which is the same as the second option except for an extra field of [C1], though I am not sure why